# How can I use global variables used between two C function which are called in Modelica?

Tags: c, function, external, modelica

I have two function definitions in C which share some global variables. I want to call these functions in Modelica but I do not know how can I correctly keep the value of the global variable between two function calls.

**file.c**

```
/*Global variable definition*/
int* global_test1;

void FirstFunc (const int* init_value){
   memcpy(global_test1, init_value, 2*sizeof(int));
} 

void SecondFunc(int* some_output_variable){
   memcpy(some_output_variable, global_test1, 2*sizeof(int));
}
```

**calling_FirstFunc.mo**

```
function calling_FirstFunc
input Integer[2,1] init_value = [3;3];
 external "C" FirstFunc(init_value);
end;
```

**calling_SecondFunc.mo**

```
function calling_SecondFunc
 output Integer[2,1] output_var;
  external "C" SecondFunc(output_var);
end;
```

**model.mo**

```
model Calling_TwoFuncs
 Integer[2,1] input_var = [3;5];
 Integer[2,1] output_var;
 equation 
  calling_FirstFunc(input_var);
 when time>5.0 then 
  output_var = calling_SecondFunc();
 end when;
end Calling_TwoFuncs;
```

Comment: What is `2*1*sizeof(int)`?

Comment: my integer variable, init_value,  is a matrix of size 2*1 and I want to allocate memory for global_test1 to be able to copy to it.

Comment: Yes but mutiplying by 1?????????

Comment: you are right, that's not needed. Edited the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code should almost work correctly. The C-functions will keep their state and work fine if (and only if) they are called in the order `First`, `Second`. You also need to allocate memory for `global_test1`... But this order is not guaranteed in the code. I suggest using [external objects](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/functions/interpolation/#defining-an-externalobject) instead; then you can create multiple instances of the same model and not have a global state in the C-code (because you can malloc memory and return this for the constructor call; the First call). Note that you should probably pass the size of the vector to the constructor in order to be more general.

Comment: thanks @sjoelund.de for your answer. I actually allocate memory for the global variable in the first function which I forgot to paste here. Thanks alot for your suggestion! I will take a look.